# add html button in vue-select sagalot

Tags: multi-select

hello folks i m using vue-multiselect is it possible to add html button in option  i.e at the end of drop down i want anchor button

```
 <v-select v-model="us" label="name" :options="option">
    <slot name="option"><a href="local">check</slot>
 </v-select>
```

option have value which i m getting from data base at end of dropp down i want anchor button is this possible  for eg as show in image add new custom is button i want something like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Np1TE.png)

Comment: what you needs to do @sunil

Comment: need button a button on select dropdown..in vue js